NullInjectorError: No provider for hr in Angular app
I'm encountering a NullInjectorError in my Angular application when I click on the login button. The error message in the console reads:
main.js:23 ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(n)[n -> hr -> hr]:
NullInjectorError: No provider for hr!
I have recently set up a login feature in my application.
The app compiles successfully without any errors.
However, upon clicking the login button, the screen disappears, and the above error is thrown in the Chrome console.
Steps to reproduce:
Click on the login button on the login screen.
Observe that the screen goes blank, and the error appears in the console.
What I've tried:
I ensured that all necessary modules are imported in my app.module.ts.
I checked the providers array for any missing services but couldn't find anything related to hr.
I looked into the component's constructor for any missing dependencies.

Please share the relevant parts of your code. Otherwise all we can do is guess.
